# How find out whether s3 file has been encrypted with Server Side Encryption

Tags: amazon-s3

When I upload file to s3 I set up the following params:

```
const upload = this.s3Stream.upload({
            Bucket: config.get<string>('CONNECTIONS.S3.bucket'),
            Key: fileName,
            ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256'
        });
```

But I don't understand how check weather I did everything right and make sure that file has been encrypted. When I downloaded file from s3 I got the original content, I only saw that against object:
[image]

I suppose that it works as described:
Server-Side Encryption – Request Amazon S3 to encrypt your object before saving it on disks in its data centers and then decrypt it when you download the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/serv-side-encryption.html

> Amazon S3 encrypts your data at the object level as it writes it to
> disks in its data centers and decrypts it for you when you access it.
> As long as you authenticate your request and you have access
> permissions, there is no difference in the way you access encrypted or
> unencrypted objects.

I'm not sure if you could get the ciphertext to ensure it's encrypted. As far as the question goes, if the console says it is encrypted server-side, you did everything right, from there it is AWS responsibility.

They are ISO/IEC 27017 compliant, (https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/iso-certified/), and that handles some cryptography issues as far as I can tell. So there is at least some verification that they are providing the service they say they are.